# Installing packages from LMDE on debian wheezy

Tags: debian, software-installation, apt, dpkg, lmde

I downloaded thunderbird from LMDE repo and tried to install it on my debian wheezy machine, using apt-get install I get a ton of this garbage output;

```
Note, selecting 'iceape-l10n-cs' for regex '.'
Note, selecting 'libhugs-time' for regex '.'
Note, selecting 'libghc-comonads-fd-prof-2.1.1.2-02108' for regex '.'
Note, selecting 'libglobus-gram-protocol-dev' for regex '.'
Note, selecting 'libgeomview-dev' for regex '.'
Note, selecting 'python-flufl.enum-doc' for regex '.'
Note, selecting 'libpath-utils-dev' for regex '.'
Note, selecting 'composite-data' for regex '.'
Note, selecting 'gimp-svg' for regex '.'
Note, selecting 'libgudev1.0-cil' for regex '.'
Note, selecting 'libfile-sharedir-perl' for regex '.'
Note, selecting 'python-reportlab' for regex '.'
```

and when I use dpkg -i I get this;

```
root@A215:/home/steven/Downloads# dpkg -i      thunderbird_24.2.0~linuxmint2+lmde_amd64.deb 
dpkg: regarding thunderbird_24.2.0~linuxmint2+lmde_amd64.deb containing     thunderbird:
hunspell-en-us conflicts with thunderbird
thunderbird (version 24.2.0~linuxmint2+lmde) is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing thunderbird_24.2.0~linuxmint2+lmde_amd64.deb (--    install):
conflicting packages - not installing thunderbird
Errors were encountered while processing:
thunderbird_24.2.0~linuxmint2+lmde_amd64.deb
```

According to Linux Mint there binary packages are 100% compatible with debian...

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

This will attempt to fix things.

```
-f, --fix-broken
    Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This 
    option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages to permit 
    APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages are specified, these have 
    to completely correct the problem. The option is sometimes necessary 
    when running APT for the first time; APT itself does not allow broken 
    package dependencies to exist on a system. It is possible that a 
    system's dependency structure can be so corrupt as to require manual 
    intervention (which usually means using dselect(1) or dpkg --remove to 
    eliminate some of the offending packages). Use of this option together 
    with -m may produce an error in some situations. Configuration Item: 
    APT::Get::Fix-Broken.
```

Then remove the `hunspell-en-us` package.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove hunspell-en-us
```

Then install the thunderbird `.deb` file.

```
$ dpkg -i thunderbird_24.2.0~linuxmint2+lmde_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but what is apt-get trying to say? It seems like useless info.

Comment: You had a dependency conflict, dpkg told you that you had a conflict "thunderbird:
hunspell-en-us conflicts with thunderbird"